# EF Core union with value conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I want my `union` LINQ query to be evaluated on server side with `EF Core`.

There're entities:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<StringWithStyle> Names { get; set; } = new List<StringWithStyle>();
}

public class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public StringWithStyle Name { get; set; }
}

public class StringWithStyle
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsBold { get; set; }
    public bool IsItalic { get; set; }
    public bool IsUpperCase { get; set; }
}
```

Their properties are stored in DbContext as `json` string using Value conversion:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>()
        .HasKey(e => e.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>()
        .Property(e => e.Names)
        .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<StringWithStyle>>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
        ,
        new ValueComparer<List<StringWithStyle>>(
            (arr1, arr2) => arr1.Count() == arr2.Count() && !arr1.Except(arr2).Any(),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())))
        );

    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>()
        .HasKey(e => e.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>()
        .Property(e => e.Name)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StringWithStyle>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
            ,
            new ValueComparer<StringWithStyle>(
                    (val1, val2) => val1.Equals(val2),
                c => c.GetHashCode())
            );
}
```

I need to show both entities in one grid. So, I use such a query:

```
var entities1 = from e1 in dbContext.Set<Entity1>()
                select new GridModel
                {
                    Id = e1.Id,
                    IsFirst = true,
                    Names = e1.Names,
                    Name = default
                };
var entities2 = from e2 in dbContext.Set<Entity2>()
                select new GridModel
                {
                    Id = e2.Id,
                    IsFirst = false,
                    Name = e2.Name,
                    Names = default
                };

var grid = entities1.Union(entities2).ToList();
```

And it throws an Exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.`

Is it possible to to get such a query that is evaluating on server side?

*** UPDATE ***

There's `GridModel` class:

```
public class GridModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirst { get; set; }
    public List<StringWithStyle> Names { get; set; }
    public StringWithStyle Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show the `GridModel` class. The question is why EF needs client-side projection to create objects of this class.

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry, I've missed it

Comment: Have you tried `Concat`?

Comment: The error explains what the problem is. That `new GridModel{` is a projection operation running on the client, using the fields loaded from the database. You're trying to apply a `UNION` on the results of the client-side projection. Why are you using `UNION` in the first place? `UNION` checks for and discards duplicates, which is an expensive operation.

Comment: EF can't handle the differences in SQL query shape due to the different parts of the model being populated. Use `entities1.AsEnumerable().Concat(Union(entities2)`. Concat because you don't need an implicit Distinct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and is there any other possibility to merge results of selecting two tables in one set?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes I did, but the result is unfourtunatly the same...

Comment: It was the last chance. Then you have to load recordsets separately and Concat on the client side.